# How to insert a "skip" after every row using the task package?

Tags: lists

Currently, I am using mainly the `tasks` package. Works quite well. The only problem is that to find a way to make `after-skip=6\baselineskip` work for every row?

Is that possible?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,enumerate}

\usepackage[more]{tasks}

\NewTasks[
counter-format={tsk[a])}, %%a,A,r,R
label-format=\bfseries,
label-width=1.5em,
label-align=left,        %% or right as you wish
label-offset=0.5em,
item-indent=2em,
after-item-skip=0pt,
after-skip=6\baselineskip,
before-skip=-0.5\baselineskip,
resume=false             %% comment this for not to resume
]{problems}[\item](3)    %% (4) here makes all of them in 4 columns

\begin{document}

%% current
\begin{problems}(3)
    \item $730+895+170$
    \item $820-456+280$
    \item $900-456-244$
    \item $89+997$
    \item $103-60$
    \item $458+996$
    \item $876-580+220$
    \item $997+840+260$
    \item $956-197-56$
\end{problems}



%% desired

\begin{problems}(3)
    \item $730+895+170$
    \item $820-456+280$
    \item $900-456-244$
\end{problems}
\begin{problems}[resume=true](3)
    \item $89+997$
    \item $103-60$
    \item $458+996$
\end{problems}
\begin{problems}[resume=true](3)
    \item $876-580+220$
    \item $997+840+260$
    \item $956-197-56$
\end{problems}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `after-item-skip` to another value than `0pt`! The default is `1ex plus 1ex minus 1ex`.

Comment: So simple! I thought that mean "each \item" rather than each "row"!